# Django does it make sense to define get_create_url(), get_update_url() and get_delete_url() for object

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

Every object which have unique url should have get_absolute_url() which usually returns detail view of the object. Often those kind of objects also have create, update and delete views and urls need some parameters to work. You can provide parameters to those urls in your templates but if you ever change your url structure etc. you have to change all your templates also instead of that one function. So: ***Is it good practice to define methods for create, edit and delete urls as well or are there some problems with that approach?***

Consider an example where I have a blog and blog owner can add posts to it, edit and delete them. Post has a foreign key to blog. Detail template for post could contain following links:

```
<a href="{% url 'post-edit' blog=post.blog.pk pk=post.pk %}">edit post</a>
<a href="{% url 'post-delete' blog=post.blog.pk pk=post.pk %}">delete post</a>
<a href="{{ post.blog.get_absolute_url }}">back to blog</a>
```

and urls:

```
url(r'^blog-(?P<blog>\d+)/post-(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', views.PostView.as_view(),  name='post-view'),
url(r'^post-new/blog-(?P<blog>\d+)/$', views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name='post-new'),
url(r'^post-edit/blog-(?P<blog>\d+)/post-(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.UpdatePostView.as_view(), name='post-edit',),
url(r'^post-delete/blog-(?P<blog>\d+)/post-(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DeletePostView.as_view(), name='post-delete',),
```

Not the best possible example but I hope you got my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least it is all up to you how you're designing your internal naming.

For me, as a long term djangoist, I'm using the very same and had never a problem. My team also loves this "development paradigm".

We're including the apps `urls.py` into the root `urls.py` and name the urls almost the same like you...except we're adding, if needed, the applications name into the url-name, too. In your example this would be `blog-post-new` or `blog-post-delete`.

#### example

```
urlpatterns = patterns('service.views',
    # /services/1/edit/
    url(r'^(?P<service_pk>\d+)/edit/$',
        view = 'edit',
        name = 'service-edit',
    ),
    # /services/add/
    url(r'^add/$',
        view = 'add',
        name = 'service-add',
    ),
    # /services/1/delete/
    url(r'^(?P<service_pk>\d+)/delete/$',
        view = 'delete',
        name = 'service-delete',
    ),
    # /services/1/permissions/
    url(r'^(?P<service_pk>\d+)/permissions/$',
        view = 'permissions',
        name = 'service-permissions',
    ),
)
```

So, do what ever feels right for you - there is no "wrong", just keep in mind that there maybe will come another app into your project with "post" ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have problems to implement my get_create_url because I need some way to pass information that which blog each post belongs to model. It does not have blog before it's created so I can't implement get_create_url() so that it returns reverse('post-new', kwargs={'blog': self.blog.pk}). In my templates it works now because add blog to context data so I can write {% url 'post-new' blog=blog.pk %}. How you do that if you implement everything inside your model? This might be a stupid question but I'm completely beginner with django :)